How do I wrap Text for a Doc Library name on the Navigation Site on sharepoint. The name is too long and the last word is not completely visible
I have built a Company Intranet Site and used vertical Navigation for various Doc Libraries and Pages etc on the left side of the site. A couple of the Doc Library names are too long  and last words of the doc Library name are not visible.I cannot shorten them as the full name of the Doc Libraries is required, hence why I want to wrap the text so the entire name is visible on the navigation sit.
